# How to count distinct daily active users using flink streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink streaming in order to replace my ETL flow.
One of the task that I working on is - calculate distinct daily active user. 
The task for itself is not too hard to implement. The thing is that I need to update the dashboard every hour about the current count.

If I create a one hour window, I will get the distinct count only for an hour but if the user back in different hour I will count him twice.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

uhmmm... Can you use the timestamp of the day as a function key? If you can do this, you can manage a little count of users in a rich function to check this. This count will automaticaly reset when the day ends.